# Throttling IObservable causes observer not being invoked

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have this simple code, which:

- creates IObservable
- sample it for half a second
- subscribes to it using ThreadPool scheduler
- observes it using SynchronizationContext

Here's the code:

```
private void DisplayPoints()
{
    var x = 0;
    var ob = this.GeneratePoints();
    ob
      .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
      .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
      .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
      .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine(d));
}

private IObservable<double> GeneratePoints()
{
    return Observable.Create<double>(o => this.GeneratePoints(o));
}

private IDisposable GeneratePoints(IObserver<double> observer)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var value = random.Next(0, 100) * (1 / (double)random.Next(1, Math.Min(50, Math.Max(i, 1))));

        observer.OnNext(value);

        i++;
    }

    return Disposable.Empty;
}
```

However, nothing is ever output on console (i.e. anonymous observer is never called). If I remove `Sample` operator, observer is called, although that behavior is clearly not intended (UI thread will get bombarded).

I am clearly missing something here. My intention is to generate data, push it via IObserver, and display some of it via UI.

**Edit:** since some people have misunderstood my intentions (even though they're clearly stated above), I should reiterate, what I'm trying to do:

- generate some data using an algorithm (`double` values seems sufficient for my problem)
- display data in GUI

Using `IObservable` and Reactive Extensions seemed like a good solution for my problem.

**Just to repeat:** I ***won't return random numbers*** in real code - this was just a **placeholder** to get my intended behavior working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to generate random number in a tight loop. Better to use a time interval. The below generates your random numbers every 200 millseconds.

```
IObservable<double> observable =
     Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMillSeconds(200))
          .Select((t,i) => random.Next(0, 100) 
                      * (1 / (double)random.Next(1, Math.Min(50, Math.Max(i, 1)))))
```

The code that Enigmativity wrote you is also effectively tight loop. The point he makes about your error pushing out values in your subscribe process is also correct. The minimal changes you would have to make to your code to get it working would be.

```
    private static Task GeneratePoints(IObserver<double> observer, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var i = 0;
            var random = new Random();
            while ( true )
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var value = random.Next(0, 100) * ( 1 / ( double ) random.Next(1, Math.Min(50, Math.Max(i, 1))) );

                observer.OnNext(value);

                i++;
            }
        });
    }
```

sometime later

```
    Observable.Create<double>((observer, token) => GeneratePoints(observer, token));
```

Note the cancellation token being passed. When the subscriber to the sequence unsubscribes this token will be set and the loop will terminate.

However this is a lot of work and Enigmativities answer is simpler and abstracts the above code away for you. It is still useful to know how to do this manually for more complex cases.

Comment: Why introduce a delay between values?

Comment: The OP asked about throttling which doesn't quite make sense in the scope of events sent out with no time interval between. I figured he might be trying to send events out with a delay in between. Your code is totally correct if you do want a dump of events. I voted you up before I answered with my own ;)

Comment: It certainly seem like the OP is introducing delay, but adding delay to the source observable may introduce unintentional side-effects. Probably not a big deal here but it can be difficult to debug this kind of thing in general.

Comment: For sure. You would have to ask exactly what the use case is and we don't have enough context except to know the OP doesn't really understand the basic RX combinators.

Comment: I'm not trying to introduce any delay. I understand now, that `Throttle` was a wrong choice of operator. My intention was clearly stated in question: generate data, push it via IObserver, and display **some** of it via UI. `Sample` _should_ meet my requirements, but as I said in comment of 
Matthew Finlay's answer, it does not work.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing - By the way, `Observable.Generate` has an overload to delay each iteration by a `Timespan` or to a specific `DateTime` - it even takes the state so you can vary it per iteration. Also, `Observable.Generate` does yield to the scheduler on each iteration (each subsequent iteration is scheduled as the preceding completes) so tight loops don't cause scheduler starvation.

Comment: @JamesWorld It's such an obvious overload I should have check for it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue is to do with the fact that `Throttle` introduces concurrency through the `DefaultScheduler.Instance` internally and that your implementation of `IDisposable GeneratePoints(IObserver<double> observer)` is non-standard.

Try reimplementing `IObservable<double> GeneratePoints()` like this:

```
private IObservable<double> GeneratePoints()
{
    return Observable.Generate<int, double>(
        0,
        i => true,
        i => i + 1,
        i => random.Next(0, 100) * (1 / (double)random.Next(1, Math.Min(50, Math.Max(i, 1)))));
}
```

That might help.

The issue comes from your observable directly pushing out values during the subscribe process. You should always try to use the standard, built-in operators when creating your observables. The above code uses the built-in `Generate` operator, so it should play nicer with your code.

Comment: `Observable.Generate` seems like better way of creating my `IObservable`. I don't like "spaghetti-ness" of this code (although adding new lines does help). I won't return random numbers in real code - this was just a placeholder to get my intended behavior working.

Answer (score 0):

`Throttle` will only let a value through when there has been a gap of at least 500 milliseconds (in your case). As `GeneratePoints` is pushing values far faster than this nothing will happen. `Sample` may be the operator you want, in this case it will produce one value every 500ms.

```
Source:       1111111111111111111----------111---111111
Throttle (5): -----------------------1-----------------
Sample (5):   ----1----1----1----1---1------------1----1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Sample` does not help - I am getting same results (observer not being called), except that lowering the sample interval below 1 ms does not invoke observer at all.